# Collections/Menu

Tags: java, collections

```
    List<Student> studentInfo = new LinkedList<Student>();

    int choice;
    boolean flag = true;
    Student student = new Student();


    while(flag)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Press 1 to Add Student details");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to Display Student details");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to Sort");
        System.out.println("Press 4 to Search");
        System.out.println("Press 5 to Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        choice = sc1.nextInt();

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:  studentInfo.add(student.addDetails());
                     break;

            case 2:  System.out.println("Details of Students are as follows: ");
                     for(Student s : studentInfo){
                         System.out.println(s);
                     }
                     break;
            //More code
```

The addDetails() method in the Student class is:

```
        public Student addDetails() 
        {
             System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
             name = sc2.nextLine();
             this.setName(name);
             return this;
        }
```

I'm using the case 1 block to take the student details and then adding them into the studentInfo collection. But, when i display the last entered details overwrites all the previous ones and when i print them out only that is displayed as many number of students that I've added. Can somebody tell me what is that I've done incorrectly? Thanks!

OUTPUT:
Details of Students are as follows: 
name=Amar, age=0, semester=0, sub_1_marks=0, sub_2_marks=0, sub_3_marks=0, percentage=0, totalMarks=0
name=Amar, age=0, semester=0, sub_1_marks=0, sub_2_marks=0, sub_3_marks=0, percentage=0, totalMarks=0

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to exactly what you're asking but splitting up a large task into small managable pieces is always a good idea. Be that on the method level or the class level

Comment: It depends (mostly on personal preferences). Is your code in one case long? Are there similar cases that can be wrapped in one method?

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm asking if its better to write a code in the above way as I've written i.e., taking all the details of the student one at a time and the adding it to a collection and so on. Or is it better to call a method in that place which does the same thing? In the latter case, should i write the method in the same class or a separate class?

Comment: @Pshemo It is long in one case and in the display case i just print the collection contents.

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj It is usually a good idea to separate the User Interface from the Business Logic. Suppose that you once want to create a graphical user interface, you can simply reuse the business logic. But apparently you already did that (I would consider `studentInfo.add()` as the business logic part). You can of course still move all the lines from the `case` block into a separate method (don't use static methods, but a method from your existing UI class). This improves testability and readability, especially if the code gets larger.

Comment: @Andreas `(dont use static methods, but a method from your existing UI class)` Why not static methods? can you elaborate?

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj They can only access static members of your class and if they do so, they introduce global state which makes the program hard to test and debug. Also, they can not be overridden in a sub class. See e.g. http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/ or http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/java-static-methods-can-be-code-smell.html

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are unsure of the answer to this question implies that it's answer may change as your code develops. If you focus on the fact that your code develops as time goes on you will often see the right path.

To me, this code already has an issue. The fact that if you wanted to add a new menu option you would have to add code in two different places (the print list and the case statement).

I would start by pulling those two areas back together into a single list of actions. Something like this:

```
static boolean exit = false;

enum Action {
  AddDetails("Add student details") {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
      // How to add details.
    }

  },
  DisplayDetails("Display student details") {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
      // How to display details.
    }

  },
  SortDetails("Sort") {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
      // How to sort details.
    }

  },
  SearchDetails("Search") {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
      // How to search details.
    }

  },
  Exit("Exit") {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
      // How to exit.
      exit = true;
    }

  };
  private final String description;

  Action(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public abstract void doIt();

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
      // Show my menu.
      for (Action a : Action.values()) {
        System.out.println("Press " + a.ordinal() + " to " + a.getDescription());
      }
      System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
      int choice = sc1.nextInt();
      // Should really do some range checks here.
      Action action = Action.values()[choice];
      // Perform the chosen function.
      action.doIt();
    } while (!exit);
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace(System.err);
  }
}
```

So - in answer to your question - use the `static methods` mechanism but only the concept. `Enum`s are a good substitute if you have a number of distinct actions.

Comment: Assuming my problem domain says the number of menu option are fixed/do not change, is it OK to write static methods in the same class/separate class and call them in the case block?
Also, I'm not fluent in using `Enum`s.

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj - There's nothing wrong with the structure you have. Each option could call a method that achieves its function. They can be `static` and in the same class for simplicity too. My point is that the grown-up way of implementing this type of process is to consider how it will change in the future and code for that. If you are not fluent in `enums` then is this a good time to learn them?

Comment: I got your point. And, its better late than never, to learn. Cheers.